Auto delete functionality in inventory table => when the quantity for the item reaches 0
I am working on making a virtual pet site. For the database schema I have developed inventory functionality. The inventory is a bridge table between the item table and the user table. It holds the items the user owns. Instead of having multiple entries of the same item in the inventory table, more than one of the same item is handled with the quantity value. When the quantity value reaches zero I want to have a trigger that deletes the item from the inventory table.
I tried this, but the trigger can't delete on the same table.

CREATE TRIGGER update_inventory_space
AFTER UPDATE
ON inventory
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE user
SET inventory_space = inventory_space + (OLD.quantity - NEW.quantity)
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
IF NEW.quantity <= 0 THEN
DELETE FROM inventory
WHERE inventory_id = NEW.inventory_id;
END IF;
END//


So I tried a helper table
CREATE TRIGGER delete_helper
AFTER INSERT
ON inventory_delete
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM inventory
WHERE inventory_delete.inventory_id = NEW.inventory_id;

it still considers it the same flow from the inventory table. So it denies it.
Is there anyway to achieve this in the database using SQL?

Leaving the solution apart, no inventory system is supposed to work the way you want it to work. Items don't disappear from the inventory. You will realize soon that you want to track when the item was placed into the inventory (+ where did it come from) and when it was taken from the inventory (+ where did it go). Selecting only items with quantity > 0 is easy. Deleting item from the inventory is almost always a bad idea.

You can't use a trigger to modify the table it is triggered from. End of story. You need to implement this in your application logic using a transaction to ensure that after the update the deletion happens as well.

set a delete flag in your tabke and write an event that deletes the rows at 3 in the morning when your database has low traffic
